# Windows Phone 8 apps for Windows Surface

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

Is it possible to develop one application that can be used for both Windows Phone 8 and Windows Surface.

Because we have developed an HTML5 mobile application that should support apple, Android and Windows Phone8, using PhoneGap. We have developed one application for for both phone and tablet in both Apple and Android.

Can we do the same for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Surface. Because the have 2 stores for each and will we be able to deploy Windows Phone 8 app to the Windows Surface store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Surface is not a Windows Phone, is a Windows Tablet, You can developp for Both with same "class Library" , but you want to have two different project. **One for Windows Phone 8** and **one for Windows 8 application**.

You can read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for better explain.

Also, I don't think PhoneGap manage Windows 8.
Unlike Androïd, You don't publish the same project for smartphones and tablet with Windows.

A Windows Phone project is just for Windows phone, a Windows 8 Application is for Tablet, Laptop and Computer using Windows 8 ^^

Comment: Actually there is a Cordova project for Windows 8 : https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Surface tablet runs the Windows 8 OS so you can't run a Windows Phone project on it. You can however build a Cordova app for Windows 8 which will run on the Surface and a Windows 8 desktop as an application.

Here is a link to the the git repository for Windows :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows

Apache URL (for cloning the latest):
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-windows.git